# 6502 beginner question: where is the carry flag?

Tags: 6502

I'm following this tutorial: https://skilldrick.github.io/easy6502/

and in the **Registers and flags** section there is a part that says *"If you were looking carefully enough, you’ll have noticed that the carry flag was set to 1 after this operation. So that’s how you know."*

The trouble is, I can't identify where the carry flag is shown.

Right before the **Instructions** it states: *"The last section shows the processor flags. Each flag is one bit, so all seven flags live in a single byte."*

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [site](https://wiki.nesdev.com/w/index.php/Status_flags), the last line in your screenshot which is `10110001` is the flags sections and the rightmost bit is the **Carry Flag**

```
7  bit  0
---- ----
NVss DIZC
|||| ||||
|||| |||+- Carry
|||| ||+-- Zero
|||| |+--- Interrupt Disable
|||| +---- Decimal
||++------ No CPU effect, see: the B flag
|+-------- Overflow
+--------- Negative
```

Comment: That visual aid made all the difference. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, glad to be able to help. It took me 5 minutes of googling, after looking at the link you provided to get some search keywords. I couldn't figure out which bit was what from your link too.